# Get each value from a list in apache velocity

Tags: html, velocity

I am new to apache velocity and stuck with a basic issue.
From the label `list1` I am passing a list of values [test1, test2, test3] to the label `list1` in the html/apache velocity file.

I need to iterate over the list and print the values in the next lines like :

```
test1
test2
test3
```

I did the following in my HTML file but this does not seem to work. It is completely ignoring the values and nothing is getting rendered in the html file. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
#foreach($values in $list1)
  $values
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it using the following code:

```
#set ($length = ($list1.length())-(1))
#set ($val = $list1.substring(1, $length))
#foreach($values in $val.split(','))
<li>$values</li>
#end
```